# How do I preserve parameters in PHP form code

Tags: php, html, post, parameters

I have a script which is run with a parameter (e.g. `details.php?studentid=10325`).

On this script I have a form with the following form code so that the form data is sent to the current script. However, what's happening is that the script is running without the parameter. How do I preserve the parameter in this form code?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Comment: You currently seem to be using the `studentid` as a `$_GET` variable. You should store the ID server-side, and submit it with as part of the `$_POST` request (server-side). Storing the student ID as a `$_GET` variable leaves you wide open for attack.

Comment: Yes I have script#1 that runs script#2 and #1 passes the ID to #2 as a parameter and #2 has the form which sends the data to itself.  So how would I store the ID server-side and submit it with as part of the $_POST request (server-side) @ObsidianAge?

Answer (score 0):

Not really recommended, but you could add a hidden `<input>` tag with the `studentid` so it is sent back when you submit the form. Like so :

```
<input type="hidden" name="studentid" value="<?= $_GET['studentid'] ?>">
```

Comment: I thought your nice idea was going to work but sadly I haven't been able to get it to work @maqc  :(  <input type="hidden" name="studentid" value="<?php echo $_GET['studentid']; ?>">

Comment: What is not working? The hidden `<input>` has to be inside the `<form>` that is submitted. Upon submitting the form, `studentid` should be accessible via `$_POST['studentid']` (and no longer `$_GET`)

Answer (score 0):

Leave the action blank, and the form will submit back to the current url

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Keep in mind you have specified post method, so the form values will come thru in `$_POST`, whereas your studentid on the query string will be in `$_GET['studentid']`, you can work around that by using `$_REQUEST['studentid']` instead, but make sure you don't have a field in the form also called studentid